# Line Integral of $y$ and $z$

Tags: integration, line-integrals

$$\int_C yz^2\,ds$$

$x = 4t,\,y = 3\sin t,\,z = 3\cos t,\\0\leq t\leq\frac\pi2$

I know how to take integrals like this, but the function is of $y$ and $z$. I usually see them in terms of $x$ and $y$, where $z=f(x,y)$.

In this question, is $x= f(y,z)$ and is the $x = 4t$ a bit of a red herring?

I've setup the integral below. Thanks

$$\int_C 3\sin t\times 9 \cos^2t\,ds$$

where $$ds = \sqrt{\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2*\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2}\, dt$$

Comment: The path of integration is along a helix: the $ \ x-$ coordinate function is not a red herring; it does not interact with the integrand, but it _does_ affect the path length of the integration.

Comment: so my ds should include dx/dt as well?

Comment: Yes, and I think you want $ \ + \ $ between the terms under the square-root, no?  You should have something rather nice for $ \ ds \ $ .  In fact, the entire integration becomes pretty easy...

Comment: Oh yes! that should be a + not a product. Thanks for your help @RecklessReckoner